# python3.6: ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

I have developed a personal site in the local with python3.8.
when I deployed the AWS ubuntu ec2 sever used the code file which deployed in the local, and when saved my blog contents, there is the following error. By the way, the site can saved well in the sever python3.6 which have been tested .

File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whoosh/index.py", line 123, in open_dir
return FileIndex(storage, schema=schema, indexname=indexname)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whoosh/index.py", line 421, in **init**
TOC.read(self.storage, self.indexname, schema=self._schema)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whoosh/index.py", line 664, in read
segments = stream.read_pickle()
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/structfile.py", line 245, in read_pickle
return load_pickle(self.file)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5

I am wondering is that a possible caused by the file in the local environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it, just deleted the pickle 5 file which generated by python3.8 version in the local. you can detect the file name in the code load_pickle(self.file) ,for example print(self.file). you can get the file position and name.